# Why is the notification observer not triggering the selector function correctly when monitoring the iOS device's power mode status?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsnotificationcenter, notificationcenter

Notification observer added to monitor the iOS device's power mode status(low power mode or not) is   not triggering the selector function correctly.

I've added a notification observer to monitor the power mode status as follows:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleSystemPowerStateChange), name: Notification.Name.NSProcessInfoPowerStateDidChange, object: nil)
```

The above line of code gets called in the viewDidLoad() of the View Controller

The code for the corresponding selector function is as follows:

```
    @objc func handleSystemPowerStateChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        
       if ProcessInfo.processInfo.isLowPowerModeEnabled {
            print("Low power mode enabled")
        } else {
            print("Low power mode disabled")
        }
    }
```

The expected behaviour is that whenever there is a change in the power mode(Low power to Normal / Normal to Low power mode), this function has to be called and the corresponding statement should be printed according to the power mode.

However this is not what happens. When I newly install a build, this function never gets called when the power mode changes.
After I reinstall the build by making any minute code changes like adding an extra empty line before the `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleSystemPowerStateChange), name: Notification.Name.NSProcessInfoPowerStateDidChange, object: nil)` or re-adding the observer, it seems to work well(Clearly unexplainable behaviour).

Note: The app is in foreground.

How can I solve this? This does not seem to be an issue with the way in which the notification observer was added or the definition of the selector function.